# How to manage read-only DB connections at an application level

Tags: java, mysql, apache, spring, ibatis

We are using Java/Spring/Ibatis/MySql. Is there a way with these technologies to manage read-only connections at an application level. I am looking to add an extra layer of safeguarding on top of having read-only MySql users. It would be nice if BasicDataSource or SqlMapClientTemplate provided configuration for read-only connections. Otherwise, it seems like I'm left to only MySql read users and enforcing interfaces with only read methods.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for example [Connection#CreateStatement](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#createStatement%28int,%20int%29) can takes parameters

```
statement = connection.createStatement
(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
```

Answer (score 2):

BasicDataSource has a property called defaultReadOnly property to set it as readonly. You can use it.

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://${db.host}:5432/${db.name}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${db.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${db.password}"/>
    <property name="defaultReadOnly" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/apidocs/org/apache/commons/dbcp/BasicDataSource.html

Answer (score 1):

Try to get the underlying `java.sql.Connection` object and `setReadOnly(true)`.