# Java db2 error SQLCODE=-913 SQLSTATE=57003 SQLERRMC=schema.table; table, driver=4.1xxx

Tags: java, jdbc, db2

I wrote a simple Java application that basically execute an `SELECT` SQL statement comprising of 4 joined tables. I then execute the SQL statement and save it to a `resultSet`. When I am looping through the `resultSet`, on the 200K+ record out of 300K+, I am getting this error message:

> SQLCODE=-913 SQLSTATE=57003 SQLERRMC=schema.table; table, driver=4.1xxx

Based on what I have read so far, this means its a deadlock error. Is it possible for this to occur on such a small resultset (300K), and on a select statement?

Comment: Can you post your code ? if your code is too big please use http://pastie.org/

Comment: It's a deadlock *or* timeout. Check the reason code to determine which, 2 = transaction branch failed due to deadlock, 68 =  transaction branch failed due to lock timeout, 72 = transaction rolled back due to an error concerning a DB2 Data Links Manager involved in the transaction, 80 = statement failed due to timeout

Answer (score 1):

A deadlock occurs when two or more transactions are in a cycle of lock wait for one another, and a lock timeout does not break the cycle. By default, when row locking is performed during a table or index scan, DB2 locks each row before determining whether the row qualifies for the query. Chances are that your table or index scan is taking too long and there are other pending transactions.

Here is a wonderful document about locks for DB2. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0509schuetz/ there is also some suggestions on how to solve locking issues.

Comment: Just thought of something else which might help you. You could put your results in read only mode. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6220709/how-to-manage-read-only-db-connections-at-an-application-level